# Git Bash regex to match latest tag

Tags: regex, git, git-bash, git-tag

My VCS has these tags

```
0.0.3.156-alpha+2
0.0.3.154
0.0.3.153
build-.139
build-.140
build-.142
build-0.0.1.28
build-0.0.1.29
build-0.0.1.30
build-0.0.1.32
```

I want to `git describe --match "<regex>"` to get the **latest** tag of the form *number.number.number.number* (so it's 0.0.3.154 in this case)

I have tried with `git describe --match "[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*$"` but it doesn't result in anything, and neither do these pattern:

```
"[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]+"
"[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]{1,}"
```

I need to get the latest tag in other to bump version for the next release. So i'm thinking of doing this automatically. Please let me know if I miss anything

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

In my build.gradle file I have a function to get tag like this (follow @Marc reply):

```
version getVersionFromTag()

def getVersionFromTag() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'tag', '|' , 'grep', '^\([0-9]\+\.\?\)\+$', '|', 'sort' , '-nr', '|',  'head',  '-1'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

Here it gives errors `Unexpected Char '\'` in the regex above. Hence I removed them to becomes `'^([0-9]+.?)+$'`, then it runs fine but in my final artifact, it does not have the version appended to the name (i.e `helloword.jar` instead of `helloword-0.0.3.154.jar`

=> My question is how should I put @Marc's suggested command to the gradle function correctly?

Comment: If the tag is the latest created tag, you could just use `git describe --abbrev=0`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The pattern after `--match` is glob, not RegEx. Try `git describe | grep ...`

Comment: @crea1 that command will return the latest tag only (here `0.0.3.156-alpha+2`). I want a command that returns the latest tag of the form like `0.0.3.154`

Comment: @ElpieKay, `git describe` will return latest tag (here `0.0.3.156-alpha+2`) so the `grep` command will just **grep** from this result. But I want to get `0.0.3.154` tag in the first place (not `0.0.3.156-alpha+2`)

Answer (score 1):

For testing I've put the output of your `git describe` in a file. This will do:

```
cat file | grep '^\([0-9]\+\.\?\)\+$' | sort -nr | head -1
0.0.3.154
```

Suppose you've created some irregular formatted tags and you want to use those as well (like your `build-`-tags) for finding the highest tag:

```
sed -E 's/^[^0-9.]*//' | grep '^\([0-9]\+\.\?\)\+$' | sort -nr | head -1
```

Comment: Hi @Marc, your command works great in Git Bash command line. Here I want to put your suggested solution into a Gradle function, but it seems there are a few issues, please see my updated Post. Thank you